# Correct way to connect a child view in ember.js pre4

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to connect a child view in Ember.js pre4.

I have the following html set as the template in the class App.ContactsShowView   :

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Show Contact</h1>    
    ID:{{id}}
</div>
 Info:
{{outlet infoarea}}
```

I would like render ContactsShowinfoView into the above outlet infoarea.

```
App.ContactsShowinfoView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'contact/templates/contactsShowinfoView',
});
```

Reading the docs it would seem that this should be done via the renderTemplate method in the Route. I've tried multiple variations of the following code:

```
App.ContactsShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate:function() {
        this._super();
        this.render( "contactsshowinfo", {
            outlet:"infoarea"

        });
    }
});
```

At best I get no error message and just get the ContactShow view displayed (But no, connect outlet).

Am I missing someting obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using consistent names for the view/template. Try this:

```
App.ContactsShowInfoView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'contact/templates/contactsShowInfoView',
});

App.ContactsShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate:function() {
        this._super();
        this.render( "contactsShowInfo", {
            outlet:"infoarea"

        });
    }
});
```